# What are the 'obscene rites of queen in Aswamedha' talked about in Sarvadarsanasamagraha by Carvakas?

Tags: vedas, charvaka

In [Sarvadarshanasamagraha by Madhavacharya](https://who.rocq.inria.fr/Ramakrishna.Upadrasta/Advaita/Sarva-Darshana-Sangraha_engl_transl.pdf), Carvakas complain that

> "authors of Vedas were...(abuses)...And all the obscene rites for the queen commanded in the Aswamedha"

My question is what are they talking about? I thought the bestiality in Aswamedha as per Satapatha Brahmana is merely symbolic. But here Carvakas, in 12th century, seems to say that these are conducted. What is happening?

Comment: The opinions of Cārvākas on issues such as yajñas, saṁskāras, etc. is immaterial. They reject Veda, smṛtis, etc. firstly. They reject karma. Furthermore, they reject pāpa & puṇya, their framework doesn't have any system of vihita or niṣiddha karman well. Therefore, a Cārvāka can't say that a particular karman is pāpa or puṇya. And if s/he does says, her/his opinion is irrelevant.
Bauddhas have a framework of pāpa & puṇya, so they can argue on that basis, but Cārvākas lack such a framework altogether. They can at most badmouth.

Comment: @Bingming but we are not talking about their ideology here. I am asking what is the 'obscene rite' mentioned by them. It is their observation here, not 'ideology'. I suspect that contrary to modern Hindu belief, Aswamedha was actually obscene involving bestiality and they reported it. I am curious to know what this forum's response is.

Comment: there is no unprejudiced observation, particularly observation of such a proper ritual as Aśvamedha by a Cārvāka. Cārvākas drop weird and disrespectful comments on many aspects of traditions, so their opinions & observations aren't prāmāṇya. It's better not to bring nonsensical opinions (of Cārvākas) with regards Veda-vihita yajñas. Bestiality is not there in any Vedasammata yajña and the act of bestiality is mentioned as a pāpa in smṛtis explicitly. Rest is upto you, you are free to suspect and take Cārvākas' observations as valid.

Comment: "the act of bestiality is mentioned as a pāpa in smṛtis explicitly" - Can you prove it? I don't know of any smriti which talks about this topic apart from Manusmriti which, afaik, recommend some penance for bestiality with cow.

Comment: *paśuveśyāgamane ca prājāpatyam* (Viṣṇu smṛti 53.7)  ; *paśuveśyābhigamane prājāpatyam vidhīyate* // [Atri smṛti 269 ; Mitākṣarā (2.290)] ; *paśuveśyādigamane mahiṣyuṣṭrīkapīstathā / kharīṁ ca sūkarīṁ gatvā prājāpatyavrataṁ caret //* (Parāśara smṛti 10.16)
And so, I have quoted 3 smṛtis, and also Vijñāneśvara's comm. Mitākṣarā on Yājñavalkya smṛti.

Comment: @Bingming Why can't we take criticisms from charvakas? To put a contradiction or absurdity, one doesn't need a concept of paap or punya.

Comment: @Bingming Medhatithi also stated a ritual in the vedas could be done, but it isn’t seen as dharma or righteous it wasn’t this one, but this commentary to me states that even regarding certain rituals they are available for one to do, but may not be seen as dharmic.

Comment: Yes I believe all Smritis clearly call for purification rights in regards to unnatural intercourse.

Comment: @Haridasa Well, that is śyena yajña, and that's an abhicāra, which is for the purpose of causing harm to others. It's totally unlike Aśvamedha. No śāstra recommends one to do śyena yajña, although it's mentioned. All dharmācāryas agree that abhicāras are niṣiddha karman.

Comment: @Bingming what of the clear beastiality I am not against many rituals, but even the very act amongst an animal or its parts should be considered immoral please explain this! 

Comment: @Haridasa Veda should not be understood on the basis of reading translations and Indological interpretations. If you want to understand something regarding a Vaidika yajña, consult a proper Vedavit Brāhmaṇa. Such a Brāhmaṇa is not Vedavit because of reading books, but by doing years of adhyayana in a śāstrīya manner. As for opinions of Cārvākas like User 29449, I have no interest in engaging in conversation with them, for they think they are above śāstras and paramparā, everyone else is wrong for them. Btw criticizing Veda is itself a pāpa tbh.

Answer (score 0):

12th Century Carvakas are not being quoted, the slokas quoted by Madhavacharya are from the Barhaspatya Sutras which are the founding text of the Charvaka school authored by Brihaspati guru of the Devas to deceive the Asuras, and in the Maitrayaniya Upanishad Brihaspati deceiving the Asuras with Charvaka doctrines is mentioned. Madhavacharya quotes Brihaspati's Barhaspatya Sutras here: [Madhavacharya's Sarvadarshanasamagraha, Chapter I, The Carvaka System](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-sarva-darsana-samgraha/d/doc79745.html)

> "And all this has been also said by Bṛhaspati—
> .
> There is no heaven, no final liberation, nor any soul in another world,
> Nor do the actions of the four castes, orders, &c., produce any real effect.
> The Agnihotra, the three Vedas, the ascetic's three staves, and smearing one's self with ashes, Were made by Nature as the livelihood of those destitute of knowledge and manliness. If a beast slain in the Jyotiṣṭoma rite will itself go to heaven,
> Why then does not the sacrificer forthwith offer his own father? If the Śrāddha produces gratification to beings who are dead,
> Then here, too, in the case of travellers when they start, it is needless to give provisions for the journey.
> If beings in heaven are gratified by our offering the Śrāddha here,
> Then why not give the food down below to those who are standing on the housetop?
> While life remains let a man live happily, let him feed on ghee even though he runs in debt; When once the body becomes ashes, how can it ever return again? If he who departs from the body goes to another world, How is it that he comes not back again, restless for love of his kindred? Hence it is only as a means of livelihood that Brahmans have established here All these ceremonies for the dead,—there is no other fruit anywhere. The three authors of the Vedas were buffoons, knaves, and demons. All the well-known formulæ of the pandits, jarpharī, turpharī, &c. And all the obscene rites for the queen commanded in the Aśvamedha, These were invented by buffoons, and so all the various kinds of presents to the priests, While the eating of flesh was similarly commanded by night-prowling demons."

Secondly  that quote just refers to the obscene rites involving the queen during the Ashvamedha Yajna, it doesn’t mean that it was actual intercourse and not mock intercourse. The whole ritual involving the queen and the horse and the Mantras uttered during that time are obscene in the sense of erotic.

Comment: The author does realize I hope the concept of canibalism and how eating from one’s own race is seen as evil..,

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely a reference to some of the erotic-seeming rituals mentioned in the Srauta-sutras or Dharma-sutra literature which involves the performer of the said ritual to place the Horse's genital organs in one's own genitalia followed by the chanting of certain mantras.

**Apastamba Srauta Sutra 20.18.4**

[image]

**Katyayana Srauta-Sutra 20.6.14**

[image]

Courstesy of the above translations to Chowkhamba publications.

Like another answer said, It could be simply mock intercourse and not actual intercourse

Comment: Doesn't seem to suggest mock intercourse though.